# could not initialize class org.netbeans.modules.android.core.sdk.DalvikPlatformManager

Tags: android, exception, plugins, netbeans-platform

I installed netbeans 7.3 and the nbandroid plug-in. Then I set Android SDK 4.0.3 or 4.1 address. Also I installed some android applications using cmd and run them on emulator just for first use! It means when I exit from netbeans and want to try again, prompt a message:

> Unexpected Exception  could not initialize class
>   org.netbeans.modules.android.core.sdk.DalvikPlatformManager

Now when I want to open an android project in netbeans, I see the message. Also I can not create a new project. I uninstalled netbeans but I see the message again. What is the problem?

Comment: how odd! restarting windows solved the problem :)

Comment: oh... the message is produced randomly In some unknown cases. i guess the problem is related to AVD settings (?)

Comment: finally i uninstalled netbeans 7.3 and installed 7.0.1 !!